# Trying to only look at specific lines in txt file TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict raises when I try

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ask questions for clarification
```

I think it would be best if I just posted my code for better understanding. So first I just simply ask the user to input a file name, just to see if it exists. And if it doesn't it exits the program.

I have a separate file containing a list of keywords, which I put into a dict

then I check if another file exists... similar to before. and with this file, Im checking to see if the keywords in the first file are contained in the second one. and calculating the sentiment value. But this is not what I need help with I just wanted to explain a little before hand

So my question is, in the section below:

```
for line in open('tweets.txt'):
        line = line.split(" ")
        lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
        long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
        if eastern.contains(lat, long):
            eastScore += score(line)
        elif central.contains(lat, long):
            centralScore += score(line)
        elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
            mountainScore += score(line)
        elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
            pacificScore += score(line)
        else:
            continue
```

how would I be able to focus on only lines in the file that contain keywords and not the entire file?

like you see in this part where I ignore lines without values?

```
with open('tweets.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
            if not values:
                continue
```

I tried methods such as creating a new file and writing the lines that contain keywords into the new file, but that raised

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict
```

but it wasnt really what I wanted to do anyways. So my first question is, how would I be able to focus on only lines that contain keywords for that section above?

```
[41.923916200000001, -88.777469199999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:24:18 My life is a moviee.

from collections import Counter
try:
    keyW_Path = input("Enter file named keywords: ")
    keyFile = open(keyW_Path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
# Read the keywords into a list
keywords = {}
wordFile = open('keywords.txt', 'r')
for line in wordFile.readlines():
    word = line.replace('\n', '')
    if not(word in keywords.keys()): #Checks that the word doesn't already exist.
        keywords[word] = 0 # Adds the word to the DB.
wordFile.close()
# Read the file name from the user and open the file.
try:
    tweet_path = input("Enter file named tweets: ")
    tweetFile = open(tweet_path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
#Calculating Sentiment Values
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    sentiments = {word: int(value) for word, value in (line.split(",") for line in f)}

with open('tweets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
        if not values:
            continue

        happyScore_Tweet = (sum(values[word]*sentiments[word] for word in values)) // (len(values))
        print(happyScore_Tweet)
def score(tweet):
    total = 0
    for word in tweet:
        if word in sentiments:
            total += 1
    return total
#Classifying the regions
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_range, long_range):
        self.lat_range = lat_range
        self.long_range = long_range
    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_range[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_range[1] and\
               self.long_range[0] <= long and long < self.long_range[1]
eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))

eastScore = 0
centralScore = 0
pacificScore = 0
mountainScore = 0
happyScoreE = 0

for line in open('tweets.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    if eastern.contains(lat, long):
        eastScore += score(line)
    elif central.contains(lat, long):
        centralScore += score(line)
    elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
        mountainScore += score(line)
    elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
        pacificScore += score(line)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to extract the lat and long.

```
import re
text = open(filename, 'r')
matches = re.findall("(\-?\d+\.\d+?),\s*(\-?\d+\.\d+)", text.read())
```

Matches will return a list of strings containing only your lat and long.

Also, there are some very good tools in python you can use for spatial queries, you should look them up.

Comment: Can you explain what you did there?

Comment: .findall allows you to find all the strings with the specified regex. It returns a list of tuple of the matching groups in the regex (the matching group are determined by the parenthesis in the regex). If you want to learn more about regex I suggest you try https://regex101.com/

Comment: Am I supposed to change this? ("(\-?\d+\.\d+?),\s*(\-?\d+\.\d+)"

Comment: No it's based on your example. [41.923916200000001, -88.777469199999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:24:18 My life is a moviee. Unless you are looking for something else.

Comment: no but I dont understand this method. Thanks anyways!